# Google Glass - overriding default gestures

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is there a way to have your Android native app or Mirror API app bypass default gestures, such as touch-hold *does not load* the Google search screen?

Answer (score 0):

No, although a better response *might* be, not yet. The Glass Development Kit (GDK) described at I/O 2013 didn't mention this capability, but it still may show up.

Unfortunately, at this time, it's speculation as to what the GDK will contain or what the Mirror API may evolve into.

It may be worth looking through the [existing issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) (or even entering an issue yourself) to see if what you're looking for has been requested as a feature enhancement.